# How do algal blooms deplete oxygen?

Tags: marine-biology, algae

How do algal blooms deplete oxygen and kill marine life? Don't they release, not consume oxygen as seaweed does? Different types of algae function differently in that respect, don't they? If they need the same things as plants (nitrogen, phosphorus), they should function the same way as plants, I thought

See, I'm trying to understand eutrophication. [This](https://hab.whoi.edu/impacts/impacts-wildlife/fish-kills/) webpage says it occurs

> when night-time **respiration** of large blooms depletes oxygen from the surrounding water

and

> can **also** occur at blooms termination, during which bacteria break down the dead algal material deplete oxygen from the water

I'm pointing this out so that you don't close this question as a duplicate of [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16685/why-is-oxygen-used-up-in-eutrophication) one. It's apparently not only something that happens only as a result of algae decomposition

1. Is it true? Do growing algae deplete oxygen too, not only bacteria that decompose them after they die?
2. In case that website is wrong why don't releasing oxygen by algae and consuming oxygen by bacteria as algae decompose balance each other out?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your post accordingly. In particular, [quotes must be referenced](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) — this is considered good practice in scientific communication and will help other users understand the context for the quote. In addition, each post should have a single clear question that includes: where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic (with references to reliable sources), and where exactly you still have questions.

Comment: @tyersome I forgot to add the link (I wrote "this", it was indicative of my intention to do so)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I specifically addressed that

Comment: Why does it not answer your question? Add to that, "What do plants do at night?" You've answered your own question; O2 is consumed in greater quantities than produced.

Comment: @anongoodnurse well, at any rate there's no answer that addresses all the raised points, neither here nor there

Comment: There is, but you seem to not be able to see ti.

Comment: @anongoodnurse See the comment of the user with the nickname Resonating under one of the answers. He asked one of my two questions, but no one replied

Comment: Do you know why? I'll be blunt here, and I'll explain. It's because **we all know why** and you just don't get it. We're trying to help you all by giving you clues without just feeding you the answers like pablum. We're professionals here, and we have a mindset of people doing some thinking for yourselves. There's a saying, "God helps those who help themselves." We aren't Gods, but we do want you to work at it a bit. See those upvotes by my comments? It means someone agrees with me. The answer is right under your nose!